# what can I use except opacity while hovering an image?

Tags: html, css, image, hover

I am trying to create a hover effect on image. As I hover, little darkness should appear on image.
For that I have tried using opacity property, it works but doesn't feel that much good or impressive. Rather it gives lightness which is not what I wanted. If you are wondering what kind of darkness I want while image being hovered, something like this, `rgba(0,0,0,0.2)` . But how do I use it?

I also played around pseudo element if I can use it, but couldn't do anything. I know what this will not work like this, but I even cannot explain now. Help me please.

```
.box::before {
 content: '';
width:100%; 
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0,2);
```

}

Following is the code with opacity, but I am trying to get little darkness as I said.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
   background:url(https://r1.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4427/Green-Nature-iPad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_200.jpg);
}

.box:hover {
  opacity:0.8;
  /*rgba(0,0,0,0.2) This is needed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use pseudo element on `hover` then set `background` as you want

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background:url(https://r1.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4427/Green-Nature-iPad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_200.jpg);
  position:relative;
}

.box:hover:before
 {
   content:'';      
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:absolute;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter grayscale in CSS.

Something like this:

```
img {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}
img:hover {
  filter: grayscale(20%);
}
```

Know more about this here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp

Comment: That can also be a good option. Thanks @AD-1.

Comment: Welcome! P.S. if you have found this helpful, could you upvote my answer? I am trying to reach 500 reputation ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method to achieve what you're looking for. You could also add a transition effect in order to make it less sudden.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
   background:url(https://r1.ilikewallpaper.net/ipad-air-wallpapers/download/4427/Green-Nature-iPad-4-wallpaper-ilikewallpaper_com_200.jpg);
}

.box:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: That seems handy ! Thanks